# How to send and receive serialized object in socket channel

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I want to transmit a serialized object over a socket channel.
I want make "Hi friend" string as serialized object and then write this object in socket channel while in the other end i want to read the same object and retrieve the data.

All these things I want to do using Java `SocketChannel`. How to do this?
I have tried like below, but did not get any data in the recipient side.

```
private static void writeObject(Object obj, SelectionKey selectionKey) {
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    try {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) selectionKey.channel();
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(channel));

        oos.writeObject(obj);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static Object readObject(SelectionKey selectionKey) {
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    Object obj = new Object();
    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) selectionKey.channel();
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(channel));
        obj = ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: The question is missing!

Comment: Is your SocketChannel already open and connected?

Comment: yes socket channel is open and connected

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your SocketChannel handling seems to be incomplete, see this **complete** example for SocketChannels transferring a byte:

```
/*
 * Writer
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

public class Sender {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Sender Start");

        ServerSocketChannel ssChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        ssChannel.configureBlocking(true);
        int port = 12345;
        ssChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));

        String obj ="testtext";
        while (true) {
            SocketChannel sChannel = ssChannel.accept();

            ObjectOutputStream  oos = new 
                      ObjectOutputStream(sChannel.socket().getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.close();

            System.out.println("Connection ended");
        }
    }
}
```

And the Reader

```
/*
 * Reader
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

public class Receiver {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Receiver Start");

        SocketChannel sChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        sChannel.configureBlocking(true);
        if (sChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 12345))) {

            ObjectInputStream ois = 
                     new ObjectInputStream(sChannel.socket().getInputStream());

            String s = (String)ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("String is: '" + s + "'");
        }

        System.out.println("End Receiver");
    }
}
```

When you first start the Server, then the Receiver, you'll get the following output:

Server's console

```
Sender Start
Connection ended
```

Receiver's console

```
Receiver Start
String is: 'testtext'
End Receiver
```

This is not the best solution, but follows your use of Java's `ServerSocketChannel`

Comment: What do you mean by "not the best solution".  Could you elaborate some more?  Also, if you wrap a stream around a channel, do you loose the NIO performance?  Thanks!

Comment: Performance isn't the correct word. What I meant is that I tried incorporating the code above to my existing 'nonblocking' NIO code, but I get the 'java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException'.  Do you have a workaround or 'better solution'?

Comment: Hi, a) the code above only works blocking. b) I wont elaborate a better solution, you shall answer a separate question for this. 
And, there is always a better solution.