# How to send String array Object over Socket?

Tags: java, sockets

I have String array object. Lets say

```
String[] names = new String[7];
```

And I am also making this object persistent by storing it into file using ObjectOutputStream on my client system. I am reading the stored object using ObjectInputStream. Upto this Okay. Now I want to send this object to another system over socket.

How to do it? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create instance of [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)
[get output stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and write to it (e.g. with [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)).

```
Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream());
out.writeObject(names);
```

You can find an example in Oracle docs: [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html).
Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453028/how-to-send-and-receive-serialized-object-in-socket-channel) should be helpful for you

Answer (score 2):

A String Array object implements the Serializable interface, therefore it can be send over a network as byte stream :

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                socket.getOutputStream());
String[] names = new String[1]; // Empty at the moment
outputStream.writeObject(names);
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: in Java Array and String are serializable types, so array of strings can be converted to string (!), send over network and than deserialized (converted back to object). See: [How to serialize object in java](http://www.wikihow.com/Serialize-an-Object-in-Java), but instead of doing that i suggest converting your data to xml, json or any other transport data format and than sending it as string. This would save you lot of trouble.

To go even further - instead of sending data that at very low level (sockets, streams, etc.) I would suggest creating higher level service and calling it via http. Frameworks like [restlet](http://restlet.org/) or [Spring remoting](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) are easy to set up.